# I am writing nested while loops which are getting impractically deep (>12 nested loops), how can i code it recursively?

Tags: python, recursion

I have some code that essentially increments a very large number, and i have some python code that does the job nicely for smaller numbers.

```
def test_loop():

    base = 3

    # increment number
    for a in range(0,2):
        b = a

        while b < base:
            c = b

            while c < base:
                d = c

                while d < base:

                    n = (d + c*base**1 + b*base**2 + a*base**3)
                    print n

                    d += 1
                c += 1
            b += 1
```

This prints out a list of the numbers that I want, upto 4 digits long when represented in base 3.
I actually need to go up to 20+ digit long numbers, and I have written code with the nested while loops getting more and more nested. I believe Python has a limit on how many levels of nesting are possible, but there must also be a better way using recursion?

Example results
0
1
2
4
5
8
13
14
17
26
40
41
44
53

Comment: With >12 nested loops, writing it recursively is a secondary concern.

Comment: Look at the `itertools` module, probably `itertools.product` is what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right that there is a limit with nested `for` loops in Python. I think it's about 20, so your solution cannot work. But even if the limit was larger, you would want to use recursion to make the code clearer, concise, and more flexible. Here's how recursion can solve your problem:

```
def list_special_numbers(base, digits, starting_digit=0, partial_sum=0):
    if digits == 1:
        for i in range(starting_digit, base):
            print(partial_sum + i)
    else:
        for i in range(starting_digit, base):
            list_special_numbers(base, digits-1, i, partial_sum + i*(base**(digits-1)))

# *** Usage examples ***

# print the list of desired numbers up to 20-ternary-digit numbers
list_special_numbers(3,20)

# print the list of desired numbers up to 30-ternary-digit numbers
list_special_numbers(3,30)

# print the list of desired numbers up to 30-binary-digit numbers
list_special_numbers(2,30)

# print the list of desired numbers up to 3-decimal-digit numbers
list_special_numbers(10,3)
```

Comment: Gary's solution definitely worked for me, but I prefer this solution. Wow, just tested it with some bigger numbers and it is seriously faster.

Comment: Have you tried Gary's solution with 30-digit numbers? :)

Answer (score 0):

You should make a function and abstract each nest. Then sum the combinations after it.

```py
def function (g, base, digit):
    return g*base**digit
```

You shouldn't use recursion on python, even with tail call functions it's not suited for it. If you want to do it anyway, use an accumulator.

Comment: Recursion in Python is absolutely fine, if you are going only a few hundred levels deep. For the OPs' problem, recursion is an elegant and fast solution. Take a look at my answer if you want.